# Progress Dialog in place of TextView, ImageView

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am loading a textview value and and image view at runtime using asychtask and it takes time and I don't want to show the progressDialog on the whole screen. Instead I want a small progress bar in the place of textview and image view. How can I achieve the same. Is it possible??
In some apps I have seen the same.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Refer to these links: http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/progress-dialog-with-an-example/ , http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/ , http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/android-progress-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do. [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) can be added as view in the layout so just add this as view on top of your image view and text view (Using say [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)) and once you have the data you can set the visibility of the `ProgressView` to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`.

The javadoc page of `ProgressBar` also has code sample that you can use use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Custom Dialog that extends `Dialog` class

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;



public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message) {
        return show(context, title, message, false);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
            boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
        /* The next line will add the ProgressBar to the dialog. */
        dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(context), new LayoutParams(40,40));
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
    }
}
```

In your Activity simply call like this to show:

```
 MyProgressDialog dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(this, null,null);
```

to dismiss also as usual `dialog.dismiss()`. You can specify attributes in style.xml

Comment: I think you have not understood me bro. I just want to show the progress dialog only in the place of TextView ( small ) as it is in the case of lazy image loading

Comment: Bro I want to like it,. this thing is ok.. but i dont want to show it for the whole page. I want to show it only for a single textview and an imageview till it gets loaded from the asynchtask. Now understand

Comment: okay then use Prograss bar in xml it self where you want show. then you can play with Visible and Gone